# Grafana Query Variables - Functions

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I am creating observability metrics which needs some variables. The variables I am looking for is currentDate or currentHour. I am adding Query type and Data Source is Prometheus, however I am not able to get result for hour() function. It is giving me some errors as mentioned in the screen shot. If I am trying this function in Prometheus console it is giving me expected output. What is a better way of using these functions ?

If it is not supported in Grafana so is there any way to define below variables:
Todays date: 2022-11-08
Hour: 14 (2pm)

Thanks in advance
[image: Grafana console]
[image: Prometheus console]

Wanted support for Grafana charts

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign Prometheus function values (or metrics values) to variables in Grafana, but you can add a query in a panel and use it in calculations or other operations in the "Transform" tab.

Ex:

[image]